# Flutter Firebase Notification Messeging

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement firebase_messaging in my flutter application. On Android Integration when i write native Application level code i got an error for duplicates classes but don't know why.

```
import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService;

class Application: FlutterApplication(), PluginRegistrantCallback {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this)
    }
    override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry?) {
        io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry?.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"));     
    }
}
```

> D8: Program type already present: com.project.my_project.Application
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
> Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
> Program type already present: com.project.my_project.Application
> at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:131)
> at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:118)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:102)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskRunnable.run(DexMergingTask.kt:444)
> ...

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeProjectDexDebug'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
> Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
> Program type already present: com.project.my_project.Application
> <

flutter doctor
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.3, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H2, locale pt-BR)
• Flutter version 1.22.3 at
/Users/developer/Documents/Documents/Development/flutter
• Framework revision 8874f21e79 (8 days ago), 2020-10-29 14:14:35 -0700
• Engine revision a1440ca392
• Dart version 2.10.3

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
• Android SDK at /Users/developer/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android
Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.1)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Xcode 12.1, Build version 12A7403
• CocoaPods version 1.10.0

[!] Android Studio (version 4.1)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.(Even know it's installed working)
✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.(Even know it's installed and working)
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.50.1)
• VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
• Flutter extension version 3.16.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
• sdk gphone x86 arm (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 11
(API 30) (emulator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it by taking an update of flutter plugin. dind't know what happens.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example from my project. I remember stumbling into something like that. I am writing just to give a quick response, not sure if this is the correct solution.

```
import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback;
// import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService;

public class Application extends FlutterApplication implements PluginRegistrantCallback {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
    registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin");
  }
}
```

Comment: The source application code it's on Kotlin. didn't work in Java .   Thanks anyway